# This constructor takes no arguments lcd

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

This is the code that I am trying to display humidity sensor data
to my lcd...

When I run this program,

> Traceback(most recent call last):    File "lcd.py", line 7 in
>   
>        lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23]) TypeErrir: this constructor takes no
>   arguments

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

from RPLCD import CharLCD

lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23])


while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
    lcd.write_string("Temp: %d C" % temperature)
    lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 0)
    lcd.write_string("Humidity: %d %%" % humidity)
```

I have put all the pins right but i am not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: Warning! RPLCD has this [bug](https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD/issues/70) an its not resolved yet. But do your own experiment with the module. May be it will help them to debug. Just wanted to warn you about the bug.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure which version of `RPLCD` you are using, but in the current stable version it says that using `RPLCD.CharLCD` directly is deprecated.  Try switching the import statement to

```
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD
```

[More documentation here](http://rplcd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as well. But realized that I was running python2. After installing latest version of RPLCD and running as python3 following worked:

```
from RPLCD import CharLCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35,
              pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23], numbering_mode=GPIO.BOARD)
# please note that numbering_mode can not be None in latest version of RPLCD

lcd.write_string(u'Hello World')
```

**Output**:[image: Displaying "hello World" in LCD]

- One more example Displaying Bus Timing. [Code in github](https://github.com/tryorfry/raspberry-pi-bus-timing-in-lcd)

[image: LCD displaying Bus Timing in SG]