# How to fix this error in raspberry PI 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I tried to run this simple code.

```
from RPLCD import CharLCD
lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23])
lcd.write_string(u'Hello world!')
```

This is showing the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lcd.py", line 2, in <module>
    lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23])
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Please help me to figure out this

Comment: From http://rplcd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html it looks like you need to import `from RPLCD.i2c` or `from RPLCD.gpio` depending how your display is connected.

Comment: TessellatingHeckler I've connected the LCD on GPIOs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This constructor takes no arguments lcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073206/this-constructor-takes-no-arguments-lcd)